# Where to place 'are' in not only... but also

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I'd like to ask which of the following sentences is correct?

1. These methods **not only are** efficient, but also raise the performance of our system.
2. These methods **are not only** efficient, but also raise the performance of our system.

Thank you!

Comment: In usage, these are interchangable and equally correct with a shift in tone but not in meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both descriptions were adjectives, I would expect to see *These methods are not only efficient but also economical.*

In your example, where the *but also* is a clause, I consider (1) to be better.

Comment: Your explanation helps me a lot. Thanks!